# What does changing the primary key of a table incur in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

In MySQL,

- whenever I change the primary key of a table, is it correct that  the original index on the original primary key will be removed, and a new index on the new primary key will be created?
- is an index based on a primary key always clustered? If yes. when changing  the primary key of a table, are the records in the table to be moved to be stored in the order of the new primary key?

Thanks.

Comment: For people wondering why their HDD goes absolutely crazy when they tamper with an InnoDB primary key - this is the question to refer to.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's default storage engine is InnoDB. InnoDB always stores a table as a clustered index, using the primary key as the clustered index. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html for details on this.

If you change the columns defined for your table's primary key, like the following for example:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (id2);
```

This will require all the pages of that table to be copied to a new layout, using the newly defined primary key as the clustered index.

This isn't the only operation that requires a table-copy. Any ALTER TABLE that changes the size of a row will perform a table-copy. E.g. adding/dropping a column, changing a data type (with some exceptions), changing nullability of a column, etc. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html for details

P.S.: I don't bother to answer about MyISAM storage engine anymore. It's on its way to being deprecated. The sooner people stop considering MyISAM as a viable option, the better.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the questions you asked:

1) Yes, a new index will be created for the new primary key.

2) For tables using the InnoDB storage engine, yes, the table will be reorganized with the new primary key as the cluster key (rows will be stored in index order by primary key; the table itself is organized as an index.) For tables using MyISAM storage engine, no.